# Apache Cordova setInterval timing error

Tags: android, cordova, setinterval

I'm using a periodic function that is called every 5000ms using setInterval in the javascript code using Apache Cordova. I'm testing it on a phone with Android 7.0. It works well for a few minutes, but usually after some time I can see that it slows down, from 5s to 10s, 15s, sometimes to more than 30s. I read that it can be related to the app being in background, but the app is out of focus from the beginning of the test and the screen is off, so why this occurs only after a few minutes? And there is an alternative way to have a more precise delay between calls?

Thanks in advance!

Fernando